# python：replace the value of a matrix with another matrix by position

Tags: python, matrix

Replace the value of `0` in matrix `A` with the value of the same position in matrix `B`, and the value of non-zero in `A` remains unchanged.
`Pandas/numpy` approaches are all acceptable.

```
A:
0 0 1
0 0 0
1 0 0
B:
0 2 4
2 0 3
4 3 0
```

The ideal result is:

```
C:
0 2 1
2 0 3
1 3 0
```

I need a concise way to handle a similar large matrix.

Comment: What kind of matrixes are they?

Comment: Is this numpy, pandas?

Comment: Pandas is best, but two-dimensional arrays are also acceptable.

Comment: @xc-2021 the approach is similar for both pandas/numpy, I provided [both solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69446284/16343464). Can you please edit your question to add this info?

Comment: @xc-2021 was the answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Assuming numpy

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0]])

B = np.array([[0, 2, 4],
              [2, 0, 3],
              [4, 3, 0]])

C = np.where(A==1, A, B)

# OR
# C = np.where(A==0, B, A)
```

output:

```
array([[0, 2, 1],
       [2, 0, 3],
       [1, 3, 0]])
```

*NB. I used `A==1` to be explicit, but implicit 1/True equality makes it possible to do `np.where(A, A, B)`*

#### Assuming pandas:

The approach is similar using [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame(A)
dfB = pd.DataFrame(B)

dfC = dfA.where(dfA.ne(0), dfB)

# OR
# dfC = dfA.mask(dfA.eq(0), dfB)
```

output:

```
   0  1  2
0  0  2  1
1  2  0  3
2  1  3  0
```

Answer (score 2):

**One possible solution could be:**

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]])

b = np.array([[0, 2, 4], [2, 0, 3], [4, 3, 0]])

c = np.where(a == 0, b, a)

print(c)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0 2 1]
 [2 0 3]
 [1 3 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have numpy 2d arrays, use numpy assignment:

```
A[A != 1] = B
```

`A` would be the desired output.

If you want a new matrix `C`:

```
C = A.copy()
C[C != 1] = B
```

Comment: I think OP clearly wants a new matrix (C)

Comment: @mozway Edited mine